# How to stop or interrupt low-level read function fetching the rest of keyboard input buffer

Tags: c, keyboard, buffer

What should I do to avoid program to self-loop through all keyboard buffer? 
I don't know very well how low-level read() function operates, but obviously it is like on a separate non-blocking thread which I can not force to stop it to receive more than I want.

For example in the below code I simply want to force the user to enter 4 characters via keyboard in terminal. But due to '\n' line feed, even when entered "123"+[enter] , the ret=read(0,buffer,4) returns 4 not 3...thus the while loop condition validates and the program enters the loop, though it shouldnt..Besides ret still gets value of 4 even when entered "1234"+[enter]...but this time meets the second problem,the while loop executes twice, thus prompting two consecutive lines of "Enter text:"...

Could you please help solve how to correctly organize the code to avoid further processing of keyboard buffer reads? as well as how to overcome "123"+[enter]=4 characters wrong evaluation?
Thnx

NOTE: if you observe the output image, please note that when entered 3 chars like "123" and "456" they are reprinted, indicating that entered inside the while-loop(although, shouldnt have)..and the second problem can be observed when entered "1234" and "7898"...they are still reprinted showing we're inside loop- that is OK...but there shouldn't be double prompts of "Enter text:" printed...they should be single lines..shows the read function somehow iterates once more over the loop, for the extra line-feed character-[enter key]... And when several chars entered, the loop shouldnt run for each input of 4 chars length, multiple times.

This is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define BUFSIZE 1000

    unsigned char end=0;

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {

        char *buffer=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE);
        char inp,*bptr=buffer;
        int ret;

        for(;;)
        {
            printf("Enter text : \n");
            /* READ automatically enters this loop even when bytes read are 
               more than 4, and it does it for each 4 next character in keyboard buffer
               */
            while((ret=read(0,buffer,4))==4)
            {
                if( !strcmp(bptr,"1111") || ret<0 )
                {
                    end=1;
                    break;
                }
                else {

                    for(int n=0;*(bptr+n) && *(bptr+n)!='\n' && n<=ret;n++) 
                        {
                            putchar(*(bptr+n));
                        }
                        putchar('\n');
                        buffer=bptr;
                    break;
                }


            }
            /* end of while loop */

            if(end) 
                {printf("End!");break;};
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Screen-shot program-output:
[image: Screen-shot program-output]

Comment: The `Enter` key is added as a newline in the input. If you ask to read X bytes, and those bytes include the newlines from the `Enter` key, that is what you will read. Perhaps you should rethink what you're trying to do and how to solve it? Perhaps create a function which attempts to read "lines" and return up to four digits and simply skips the rest of the line? Perhaps read the full lines, and do some input validation in your code so you can tell the user that the input was invalid?

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), like that `0` in the `read` call. Use e.g. `STDIN_FILENO` instead. Makes it much clearer where you're really reading from even at a quick glance.

Comment: Note that after reading 4 bytes, you are comparing 5 bytes with `strcmp(bptr,"1111")`. Also you check `ret<0` but already know it is `4`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude First and foremost, I am trying to figure out how exactly the read function works for **stdin** otherwise surely enough I can formulate what I want to achieve by help of **getchar()** or **fgetc()** etc... Actually I am studying now on unix sockets, so to see visually and easily of the function of read(), I exercise on stdin with read() for the moment.   And furthermore, I have no means of getting rid of **[Enter]** keypress when on terminal input...Besides it suits me best to tackle such obstacles, so as to gain full control of read() over any buffer. Thnx

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, you are right about ret<0, it is a left-over from recent code..But because it was out-of-subject, I didn't change it. I know it is obscure and meaningless...Thnx anyway. But I didnt get what u meant by saying "...comparing 5 bytes"? well...it is 4bytes+'\0'...not 5 bytes...besides this comparison works perfect...The program breaks and terminates when entered "1111" - 4 chars length plus enter key hit of-course... I don't see problem in this line of code...sorry

Comment: Yes, I wonderered where the essential `'\0'` comes from for data passed to a string handling function, because `malloc` does not initialise memory and it does not come from `read`. Could this be where your extra-long output string comes from? An unterminated string?

Comment: You use `bptr` as a null-terminated string, but `read` is a raw and (as you say) low-level function which have no idea about such things. You need to make sure that the data is truly a null-terminated string (by doing e.g. `bptr[ret] = '\0'`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ... I have tried that...inserted exactly same code inside first else block right before for loop, but that got things even more unpredictable. pls check yourself..the point is how to interrupt and force and exit from this read system call by means of C directive? I tried many many things...but in the meantime I try not to make code bigger...and not use other functions or built-in macros.

Comment: if you want to strip out non alphanumeric chars from a buffer, you can use a function like isspace ( on  linux) to copy characters to a second buffer. Read, as has been pointed out, does only what it says - it copies at most x number of *bytes* into a buffer, treating them as raw bytes, not as characters. That is how read is defined.

Comment: @secretsquirrel , well, it might be so that read is defined to do so as you describe...but their ignorance on mentioning if it makes its call ONCE or TILL the end of the input buffer, is not mentioned... So the point of subject I see many don't yet understand... simple!.How to STOP read() calling itself, after predetermined times? Let's say I want to read only 4bytes, and ONE time....But if input buffer has 100bytes already fed....How  to stop read() looping reading sessions each of 4bytes length? Regardless of line feed or whatsoever...continued-

Comment: @secretsquirrel ...So, to visualize what I say, assume [e] means [enter key](which is 0x0A char code ASCII)
 Buffer is: "1234[e]567890[e]12"
 read(stdin,buf,4) outputs AUTOMATICALLY this series;
- 1234 , -[e]567, -890[e] , -12
And if the outpuf file is stdout-that is screen, instead of [e] you see new line starting.
So how to solve this issue?How to make that read() func. stops at the end of "1234" in this visualisation let's say?entering number 4 as size in third argument DOESN'T stop it.it just sets the size of PACKETS to receive.that's not the limit to stop.(As far for stdin is such)

Comment: of course one solution is I can create a static variable initialized to zero, and then set it inside while and check it's value inside while condition...but that's a TRICK, not a solution!

Comment: again, the problem is not read. Why is read responsible for what goes to stdout ? Read just does what it is defined to do. YOU are calling read, it's not calling itself. Its up to YOU to filter the output of read and write to stdout.

Comment: @secretsquirrel Well, then pls tell me how to achieve the result I mentioned? What's wrong in my code logic?

Comment: well, thnx all for bearing my silliness...I got what I wanted...just a matter of conditinals arrangement was the issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of ways to do this, but if you really want to use read, you can copy the contents of the buffer filled by read to a second buffer something like so:

```
char tempbuf[4];
int index = 0;


while((ret=read(0,buffer,4))==4)
        {
            index = index % 4;
            for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
            {
                if(!isspace( buffer[i]) // or if(buffer[i] != '\n')
                tempbuf[++index] =buffer[i];
             }
            if( !strcmp(tempbuf,"1111") || ret<0 )
            {
                end=1;
                break;
            }
            else {

                for(int n=0;*(bptr+n) && *(bptr+n)!='\n' && n<=ret;n++) 
                    {
                        putchar(*(bptr+n));
                    }
                    putchar('\n');
                    buffer=bptr;
                break;
            }


        }
        /* end of while loop */

        if(end) 
            {printf("End!");break;};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int ret;

    for(;;)
    {

        printf("Enter text : \n");

        while((ret=read(0,buf,4))==4)
        {

            buf[ret]='\0';

            if(!strcmp(buf,"exit"))
            exit(0);

            if(buf[ret-1]=='\n') break;
            else {
                printf("-- entered : %s \n",buf);
            }

        }/* end of while loop */
    }/* end of infinite loop */

            return 0;
        }
```